# Java spring Mockito does not mock MongoDb service

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service

```java
@Service
public class ShopServiceImpl implements ShopService {

    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    public ShopServiceImpl (ShopRepository shopRepository) {
        this.shopRepository= shopRepository;
    }
...
}
```

and I want to write test with mocked Mongo database to test the CRUD methods.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetShopServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private ShopRepository ShopRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private ShopServiceImpl shopService;

    @Test
    public void randomTest() {
        ...
        Shop shopSaved = shopService.save(shop);
        List<Shop> shopsRetrieved = shopService.listShops();
    }
}
```

But this mocked service does not save or retrieve saved record. I do not have any configurations that relate to mocked mongo db, but tried them and they didin't work. What to do?

Comment: *mocked service does not save or retrieve saved record* Can you explain what your understanding of a _mock_ is?

Comment: Mocked services act as a fake ones to imitate their job. They also should use mocked databases so it would not interfere with production/dev db's. Is that not right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@DataMongoTest`.

[Sample Implementation](https://rieckpil.de/mongodb-testcontainers-setup-for-datamongotest/)